# how to get latest 10 visitor for each item

Tags: java, redis

I have a web application now. I just to want to get latest 10 visitor who have seen some specify item. But I do not want to save all the visit info to mysql. Is there any better way to implement the feature?

As I am using redis, dose redis have some feature to support such situation?

Comment: Please share some samples you have tried

Comment: Databases are made for storing information. If you don't want to use the database for this, it would be good to know which requirements are against this, to be able to find a more fitting solution.

Comment: The point is the level of persistence needed. For a visitor list you do not necessarily need a database persistence. Imagine it is a site under heavy load, you will bother the Db with constantly updating/retrieving this information, which is much better placed into a "shared memory" like Redis can be. No disk access, very lightweight protocol. Typically this info does not need to survive a cold boot. Even if needed Redis could be clustered.

Comment: yes, if I keep them to the database, I will visit the db too  frequently. And I should keep the list of 10 visitors for each item all by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the the latest viewers per item as a List in Redis, and keep each List to exactly 10 visitors by using `LTRIM` on it.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the redis operations. Can you show the command example for me. And I am using Spring data redis now, the java code is better, thank you!